# Ajax передача переменной в POST-запросе

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть такая форма.

```html
<p class="postinfor">Заголовок</p>
 <textarea name="title" id="titlenews"
 cols="50" rows="2"></textarea>
 
 <p class="postinfor">Текст</p>
 <textarea name="message" id="postmsg"
 cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
 
 <p><input type="submit"
 id="post_submit"
 value="Отправить"></p>
```

И ajax обработчик

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
// ajax post
$(function() {
$("#post_submit").click(function() {

var text = $("#postmsg").val();
var title = $("#titlenews").val();
var dataString = 'message='+ text;

if(text=='')
{
}
else
{
$("#flash").show();
$("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="background/ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle">');

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "post.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("ol#update").prepend(html);
$("ol#update li:first").slideDown("slow");
document.getElementById('postmsg').value='';
document.getElementById('postmsg').focus();
$("#flash").hide();
}
});
} return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Не могу передать переменную `title`. Просто в ajax еще плохо разбираюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот этот кусок кода

```
var text = $("#postmsg").val();
var title = $("#titlenews").val();
var dataString = 'message='+ text;

if(text=='')
{
}
else
{
$("#flash").show();
$("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="background/ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle">');

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "post.php",
data: dataString,
```

нужно заменить на

```
var text = $("#postmsg").val();
var title = $("#titlenews").val();
var dataString = {'message': text, 'title':title};

if(text=='')
{
}
else
{
$("#flash").show();
$("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="background/ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle">');

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "post.php",
data: dataString,
```

Comment: @KoVadim Все получилось спасибо вам большое.